# If $p^q - 1$ is a prime, then $p=2$ and $q$ is a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I was working my way through some number theoretic proofs and being a newbie am stuck on this problem :

> If $p$ and $q$ are positive integers ($\mathbb{Z}^+$) such that $q \gt 1$ and $(p^q - 1)$ is a prime, then $p$ is $2$ and $q$ is a prime.

***My Question :***

> I am unable to make any concrete progress . Even a decent hint would be acceptable so that I can build on that ...

Comment: Something looks wrong here. $2^i$ is prime if and only if $i=1$.

Comment: $p^q$ cannot be a prime, since it is divisible by $p^n$ for all $0<n<q$.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel , sorry :) ; corrected the question !

Comment: @barakmanos , sorry :) ; corrected the question !

Comment: You're referring to [Mersenne primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).

Comment: @pranav I gave you an answer below. I left some things undoene by your request. Tell me if you can do it from there on your own.

Comment: Note that the opposite direction is not necessarily correct (with the smallest example being $2^{11}-1=23\cdot89$).

Comment: Thanks @barakmanos , your link was of great help :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since if $p$ is odd then $p^q-1$ is even and larger then two you must have $p=2$.
Now, if $q=ab$ then $p^q-1$ is divided by $p^a-1$. (show it).
Form here $q$ must be prime.

Comment: @pranav: It is (at least most of it), but here it's Mathematics community.

Comment: Hi , @OfirSchanbel , thanks a ton :) , I got it :) . The Math.SE community is awesome :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Aren't you are missing the case $p$ even and larger than $2$?